Only last notification appears on iOS after switching to online
regards documentation of Firebase I have (I suppose) collapsible message.
I had a similar problem with Android, but after removing the whole notification object from the payload it started working.
But on iOS sending notification with (only) data as payload nothing helped - only last notification appears after switching network from offline to online.
Honestly, I tried many different ways (with or without apns header, without apns etc.) and I see a dead end. Help!
For now, my payload looks:
message: {
  token: 'some token',
  data: {
    title: 'some title',
    body: 'some body',
    content_available: 'true',
    priority: 'high'
  }
}

And I'm sending using Rest API
I'm using:
System:
    OS: macOS 12.7.4
    CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4770HQ CPU @ 2.20GHz
    Memory: 3.49 GB / 16.00 GB
    Shell: 5.8.1 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 16.17.1 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.17.1/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.19 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.17.1/bin/yarn
    npm: 9.8.1 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.17.1/bin/npm
    Watchman: 2024.01.22.00 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.15.2 - /Users/darek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/bin/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: DriverKit 22.2, iOS 16.2, macOS 13.1, tvOS 16.1, watchOS 9.1
    Android SDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 2022.3 AI-223.8836.35.2231.10671973
    Xcode: 14.2/14C18 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: 11.0.21 - /usr/local/opt/openjdk@11/bin/javac
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 18.2.0 => 18.2.0
    react-native: 0.71.17 => 0.71.17
    react-native-macos: Not Found


"@notifee/react-native": "7.8.0",

and

"@react-native-firebase/analytics": "19.2.2",
"@react-native-firebase/app": "19.2.2",
"@react-native-firebase/messaging": "19.2.2",
(also tried 18.8.0, 18.9.0)


The behaviour you are describing for iOS is expected.
If a device is offline, APNS may coalesce messages for an app and only deliver the most recent:


If APNs doesn’t deliver a notification immediately, either for device power considerations or because the destination is offline, it may coalesce notifications for the same bundle ID.


Push notifications on iOS do not provide guaranteed delivery.  They should not be considered as an alternative to your app fetching data from a server.  A silent push notification can be used as a trigger to tell your app to fetch data from the server.
